# Jinja2 template if statement with flask not executing on authenticated user login

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-login

I am trying to create a blog application with flask and I have gotten as far registering a user and successfully logging them in. My issue lies when the user is successfully logged in, they are authenticated but stay authenticated no matter what and my links in the template are not rendering correctly. I have a layout.html file that has in **if statement** but the `current_user.is_authenticated` property is not working.

I have tried restarting the server, clearing browsing data in the browser,
printing the values of the User to see if they are authenticated as True; all of such has not worked.

### layout.html

```
      <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Account</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
      </div>
```

If the user is authenticated the if block should execute and the links on the page should render different to have a logout feature

### routes.py

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    print("first auth check",current_user.is_authenticated)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            print('login success:')
            print("second check",current_user.is_authenticated)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Failure. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
    
@app.route("/account")
@login_required
def account():
    return render_template('account.html', title='Account')
```

### models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    except:
        return None

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Before I go any further through the post: "but the `current_user.is_authenticated` method is not working". It won't. If it's a method, you didn't call it with `()`

Comment: (it's not a method btw but a property). But it is enough to make the question confusing before having to wade through a huge amount of text and code. Please give a [mcve]. I'm also getting deja vu; I'm sure I've seen this question recently

Comment: You have `from flask_login import UserMixin` but then don't use it, and then roll your own checks for some of the conditions.

Comment: @roganjosh I have tried using the UserMixin as a passed parameter to User class but that didnt work so I removed it before asking this question and added those checks that I found in the flask documentation but left the import statement. I am sorry for the long drawn out code examples but I wanted to include enough for someone to be able to understand what I am doing wrong and help correct me. I am quite new here so sorry to make this confusing/harder than it should be.

Comment: @roganjosh as to your comment about `current_user.is_authenticated` I now understand why this is a property and not a method, thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @roganjosh do you see any other reasons why the user is always authenticated upon returning to the web app after restarting the server? Also I do no understand at all why the Links in the layout.html file are not rendering as I know the user is authenticated but the if block is not executing and rendering the Logout link in the nav bar?

Comment: IMO; Go back to "I have tried using the UserMixin as a passed parameter to User class but that didnt work". Deviating from that was probably a bad idea, so the problem starts there. You'd be better starting with that, but did you read my [mcve] link?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh I have read this link over and I will edit this post to reflect that here shortly. I will also change up the code and use the UserMixin parameter for the User class. I didnt have luck with that before but it will be a good starting point. I wanted to pass along the git repo link for this tutorial so it might be easier for you to see the problem I am having. I appreciate the comments and help! https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/06-Login-Auth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204232/discussion-between-austin-griffith-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion the problem here

```
class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Try adding

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```